# Problem with self-closing DIV tags with XRechnung Visualizer and Saxon-HE for .NET

Tags: html, xslt, transform, saxon

I want to implement a XRechnung visualizer with .NET/C# by using [itplr-kosit's xrechnung-visualization](https://github.com/itplr-kosit/xrechnung-visualization), to transform XRechnung to HTML. As processor I use [Saxonica's Saxon-HE](https://www.saxonica.com/products/products.xml). Now I'm struggeling with invalid HTML as output in the form of self-closing DIV's.

The transformation code is as follows:

```
public static string TransformXml(string xmlData, string xslData)
{
    var xsltProcessor = new Saxon.Api.Processor();

    var documentBuilder = xsltProcessor.NewDocumentBuilder();
    documentBuilder.BaseUri = new Uri("file://");
    var xdmNode = documentBuilder.Build(new StringReader(xmlData));

    var xsltCompiler = xsltProcessor.NewXsltCompiler();
    var xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler.Compile(new StringReader(xslData));
    var xsltTransformer = xsltExecutable.Load();
    xsltTransformer.InitialContextNode = xdmNode;
    
    var results = new Saxon.Api.XdmDestination();
    xsltTransformer.Run(results);

    return results.XdmNode.OuterXml;
}
```

The calls:

```
var xmlData = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "xrechnung.xml"));
var xslDataToXR = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "cii-xr.xsl"));
var xslDataToHTML = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "xrechnung-html.xsl"));

var xrXMLData = TransformXml(xmlData, xslDataToXR);
var htmlData = TransformXml(xrXMLData, xslDataToHTML);

File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "result.html"), htmlData);
```

Works ... up to the problem, that in the resulting HTML all fields which are not filled are transformed to **self-closing DIV tags**.

For example, the following snippet out of the `xrechnung-html.xsl`...

```
<div class="boxzeile">
  <div class="boxdaten legende">Postfach:</div>
  <div id="BT-51" title="BT-51" class="boxdaten wert"><xsl:value-of select="xr:BUYER_POSTAL_ADDRESS/xr:Buyer_address_line_2"/></div>
</div>
```

... will be rendered as following HTML, because the xml doesn't provide a value for `Buyer_address_line_2`:

```
<div class="boxzeile">
  <div class="boxdaten legende">Postfach:</div>
  <div id="BT-51" title="BT-51" class="boxdaten wert"/>
</div>
```

The browser interprets the self-closing DIV as open tag and the complete view is broken.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you let Saxon do the serialization by not using an XdmDestination but by writing directly to a file or stream or string writer using a Serializer then I am sure it honours HTML serialization rules. In the context of XML and XSLT I would recommend to let input parsing and output serialization be handled as much as possible by the XML parser and XSLT processor instead of reading in strings from files or writing strings to file with File APIs.

As you seem to want to chain two transformations I guess using

```
  var xslt1 = xsltExecutable1.Load30();
  var xslt2 = xsltExecutable2.Load30();
  
  using (var inputStream  = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "xrechnung.xml")) {
    using (var resultStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "result.html") {
      xslt1.Transform(inputStream , xslt2.AsDocumentDestination(xslt2.NewSerializer(resultStream)));
    }
  }
```

is a viable approach.

Of course changing two stylesheets is also possible directly in XSLT 3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="step1-uri" as="xs:string">https://github.com/itplr-kosit/xrechnung-visualization/raw/master/src/xsl/ubl-invoice-xr.xsl</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="step2-uri" as="xs:string">https://github.com/itplr-kosit/xrechnung-visualization/raw/master/src/xsl/xrechnung-html.xsl</xsl:param>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:sequence
         select="transform(map {
                   'source-node' : .,
                   'stylesheet-location' : $step1-uri
                 })?output ! transform(map { 
                               'source-node' : ., 
                               'stylesheet-location' : $step2-uri 
                             })?output"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In general one could use `fold-left` to chain a sequence of stylesheets:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="step1-uri" as="xs:string">https://github.com/itplr-kosit/xrechnung-visualization/raw/master/src/xsl/ubl-invoice-xr.xsl</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="step2-uri" as="xs:string">https://github.com/itplr-kosit/xrechnung-visualization/raw/master/src/xsl/xrechnung-html.xsl</xsl:param>

  <xsl:param name="xslt-locations" as="xs:string*" select="$step1-uri, $step2-uri"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:sequence
         select="fold-left(
                   $xslt-locations,
                   .,
                   function($doc, $xslt-location) { 
                     transform(map { 'source-node' : $doc, 'stylesheet-location' : $xslt-location })?output
                   }
                )"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After some fine tuning, it works as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you serialize the result as HTML (or XHTML) rather than XML.

You are currently sending the results to an in-memory tree and then serializing this using the `OuterXML` property, which gives you an XML serialization.

Instead, send the output to a Serializer, and select serialization method HTML either using `<xsl:output>` in the stylesheet, or by setting properties on the `Serializer` object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Martin's answer. I am able to figure it out. Here is a complete function.

```
public static string XmlToHtmlWithSaxon(byte[] xmlData, byte[] xslData)
{
    Processor processor = new Processor();
    XsltCompiler xsltCompiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
    XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    readerSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
    string htmlResult = null;
    using (MemoryStream msXslt = new MemoryStream(xslData))
    {
         using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(msXslt, readerSettings))
         {
             xsltCompiler.BaseUri = new Uri("file://");
             XsltExecutable xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler.Compile(reader);
             var xsltTransformer = xsltExecutable.Load30();
             using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(xmlData))
             {
                 using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
                 {
                     xsltTransformer.Transform(inputStream, processor.NewSerializer(outputStream));
                     htmlResult = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outputStream.ToArray());
                  }
             }
         }
      }
     return htmlResult;
}
```